# VBA creating chart error

Tags: excel, vba, charts, pivot-table, excel-charts

I am trying to create a chart from pivot table but I am getting an error. My code is given below:

```
Sub Chart()
'
' chart Macro
  Dim shp As Chart

'
    Set shp = Charts.Add
    Worksheets("pivot").Select
    Range("B5:E5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$3:$E$5")
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Tools Sold"
    With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Consolidated"

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("charts").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    ActiveChart.ShowValueFieldButtons = False
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("charts").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels

    End With
End Sub
```

I got a run time error when I debugging line

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("charts").LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
```

I am a beginner. So not be able to resolve this issue. I am also attached the error screenshot and the line.
How to resolve this issue? [image]

Comment: Probably your chart (and therefore the ShapeObject) is not named "Chart"

Comment: @FunThomas - are charts ever referred to as a `ShapeObject`?  I thought they were referred to as `ChartObjects` as in `ChartObjects("Chart 1")`?

Comment: @ashleedawg: The macro recorder does so if you set the `LockAspectRatio` (and I couldn't find a way on the quick to do the same with the Chart Object)

Comment: Click on your chart and see to the left of formula bar to check the name of the chart.

Comment: @ashleedawg:Then how to do this?

Comment: Imran Malek: If I hardcore the chart name as it shows on the left panel from next time when I run the code that name got changed.Then How do I create it globally?

Comment: @Shaon - What is the **name** of your chart?

Comment: @ashleedawg:Any name which I can write for a global chart.

Comment: @Shaon declare a shape object and assign it a chart name just before the line where you are getting error.

Comment: @Shaon -  No, I'm saying you need to refer to the Chart by it's name in this case. Right now your code is looking for a chart named `charts`.  If you're not sure what it's named there are various ways, including the procedure I added to my answer (below).

Comment: Also, your code is creating 2 charts. Is that intentional?  Regardless, I think you have more than one issue with your code; I would suggest starting over with chart creation, by recording your steps (as mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784990/8112776).)

Comment: @ashleedawg:No.

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines before the error message and refer to your chart with the name given with cht.Name

```
Dim cht As Shape
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    cht.Name = "chart001"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that when you're trying to automate any of Excel's built-in tasks, instead of trying to figure out the exact VBA yourself, you use the **Macro Recorder** to record your actions as you do the steps *manually* (in this case, create a chart from a PivotTable), and then you and view and edit the generated code as required.

---

### Edit:

If you're not sure what your chart is named, one way to find out is by running this:

```
Sub ListCharts()
    Dim x
    For Each x In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
      Debug.Print x.Name
    Next x
End Sub
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the Immediate Window to view the results (if it's not already open).

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code)
- MSDN : [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros)
- MSDN : [**Creating PivotTable Reports and Charts with VBA in Excel 2010**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/hh243933.aspx)
- MSDN : [**`ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio` Property** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/shaperange-lockaspectratio-property-excel)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need neither any shape object nor all that activating/selecting

```
With Worksheets("pivot").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivot!$A$3:$E$5")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Consolidated"
    .SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    .SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
    .SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Tools Sold"
End With
```

Comment: Even if you went on and changed your code, you may want to give proper feedback and close this question. Thank you,